DHCP Reservation with Network Manager in AP mode
I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.4 on a Raspberry Pi. I installed NetworkManager and added a config file somewhat like this:
# /etc/netplan/10-my-config.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
  wifis:
    wlan0:
      access-points:
        "base-ap":
          password: "12345678"
          mode: ap
      dhcp4: true
      optional: true
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.10/24

And what I want to achieve is that, when specific devices connect to the Pi/AP, they always get the same IP address (possibly based on the MAC address of the device).
Is that possible? Any pointers would be appreciated!

Modify your dhcpd.conf file,   https://linux.die.net/man/5/dhcpd.conf ->  search for use-host-decl-names  , there is an example. you can change the domain to the ip address you want and skip the decl-names on line.

@Schmaehgrunza I don't think I have that conf file (or have dhcpd at all?). Should I install it first? Would networkmanager/netplan "automatically" utilize the newly installed dhcpd? Or would I need to somehow tell it to use dhcpd?

https://raspberrytips.com/dhcp-server-on-raspberry-pi/

does you router act as DHCP server? Ive netgear router and can config DHCP server on router, static IPs for Mac Addresses

@Schmaehgrunza Thanks for the replies! I'm hoping to use the Pi as the router in this case, and have a few other iot devices connected to the Pi, so that this setup can be more portable, instead of having to configure the actual routers everywhere I go. I think either dhcpd or like in your link dnsmasq could work, but I'm struggling a bit to figure out how they'd work with Ubuntu OS and its default network stuff..

ever heard of avahi service?. Multicast DNS. if you install that on all machines in your LAN you dont need a specific IP for a device. You can connect by hostname hostname.local of your LAN device. There are only two lines in the config file, where you must remove the comment character.
